# Fixing numbering of figures and sections when using paracol package

Tags: paracol

I'm using the `paracol` package to create a multicolumn format. Whenever I have to switch columns, I use the `\switchcolumn` argument. My issue is that whenever I do that, my figures and sections are numbered inconsistently.

[image]

As you can see, the 1st image in my right hand side column is labelled "Figure 1" again when that should be figure 2. It does the same thing for a section title - if its on the right hand side, it also restarts the numbering from one as opposed to a continuation from the numbering on the left hand column. Is there any way to fix this?

This is how my document is structured

```
\begin{paracol}{2}

\section

*text

*figure

*text

\switchcolumn

*figure

*text

*figure

\switchcolumn

\section
.
.
.

\end{paracol}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to use `paracol` for this kind of two column layout? As far as I can tell from the screenshot,  the text basically is supposed to run down the left column and then switch to the right column. Is that correct? Such a layout can simply be created using a `twocolumn` documentclass or with the help of the `multicol` package. `paracol` on the other hand is intended for synchronized columns or "parallel" text (e.g. a text in one column and comments or a translation on the other column), a feature, I can't see from your screenshot.

Comment: @leandriis ```multicol``` makes it difficult to keep figures in the same place that they're in within the structure of my document. I'll try ```twocolumn``` though

Comment: To answer your question, paracol maintains two (or more) sets of counters, unless you use \globalcounter (page 6).

Comment: paracol is really not designed for documents where the flow goes from the left column to the right, it is for documents with two parallel flows and reading order goes from bottom of the left column to top of left column on next page.